# Hibernate Join between 2 tables with foreign key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

Im trying to get a list with results from join with two tables, but always get error.
What i want is List with person and job name

- **Error**

  - *Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.setAllPropertyFetch(boolean)" because "fromElement" is null*
- **My tables**

  - *Person*

    - int id
    - text name
    - int job_id (foreign key with table JOB(id))
  - *Job*

    - int id
    - text name
- **Entities**

  ```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "person")
  public class Person{

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  int id;
  @Column(name = "name")
  String name;
  @Column(name = "job_id")
  int jobId;

  public int getId() {
      return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
  }

  public int getJobId() {
      return jobId;
  }

  public void setJobId(int jobd) {
      this.jobId= jobId;
  }
  public String getName() {
      return name;
  }

  public void setName(int name) {
      this.name= name;
  }


  @Entity
  @Table(name = "job")
  public class Job{

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  int id;
  @Column(name = "name")
  String name;

  public int getId() {
      return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
      return name;
  }

  public void setName(int name) {
      this.name= name;
  }
  ```

  - DAO

  ```
      public class PersonDAO {
      @Autowired
      private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

      public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf) {
          this.sessionFactory = sf;
      }

      public List<Person> getAllPerson() {
          Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
          List<PersonResponse> list = session.createQuery("from Person p left join p.jobId").list();
      }
  }

  - PersonResponse
      - POJO with Person parameteres/variables without annotations and job name.
  ```

Comment: what is the relation type? manytomany, manytoone? onetomany?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use `left join` in hql you should correct your mapping for `Person` in the following way:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person
{
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "job_id")
   Job job;

   // ...
}
```

and then you will be able to write hql query like this:

```java
List<Person> list = session.createQuery("select p from Person p left join p.job").list();
```

Comment: Thanks. And about save?? How i should handle the job? because on save i just have id, not all object

Comment: In general it is a good practice use separate DTO objects for client-server communication and do not use for this purpose jpa/hibernate entities.

Comment: You mean, one object for save/update and other for queries? I think it doesnt make sense,since have the same variables,except the "mayToOne" relation

Comment: At start point the difference between these objects may be minimal. But after a while to keep both in one will be more and more difficult. And please note that you can not just save what you get from the request. Look for example on [this](https://xebia.com/blog/jpa-implementation-patterns-saving-detached-entities/) article for additional potential problems description.

Comment: I guess i found a solution https://vladmihalcea.com/manytoone-jpa-hibernate/